# Spring Boot JPA - ManyToOne relationship causes extra sql

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, eclipselink

I have 3 objects with simple relationship which looks as follows:

University:

```
@Entity
public class University {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String name;

}
```

Faculty:

```
@Entity
public class Faculty {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @Column(name = "university_id", nullable = false)
  private Long universityId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinFetch(value = JoinFetchType.OUTER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "university_id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private University university;
}
```

Specialty:

```
@Entity
public class Specialty {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @Column(name = "faculty_id", nullable = false)
  private Long facultyId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinFetch(value = JoinFetchType.OUTER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "faculty_id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Faculty faculty;
}
```

I am using EclipseLink and Spring CrudRepository to operate with these entities.
When i call

> specialtyRepository.findAll();

i get sql

> SELECT * FROM specialty LEFT OUTER JOIN faculty ON (faculty.ID = specialty.faculty_id) ...

and extra sql like

> SELECT * FROM university WHERE ((ID = ?)) ...

I want to prevent this sql request;

Could someone tell me how to resolve this issue? 
Thank you for any tips

Comment: Remove `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`, or write and execute a JPQL query that uses `left join fetch` in order to load the specialty and its faculty all at once.

Comment: I want to solve it without custom query;  `Remove fetch = FetchType.LAZY` - it did not help; Is it possible to ignore University relationship in Faculty; I just need simple specialty information with faculty information without nested relation (university must be equal to null in faculty object)

Comment: those extra sql statement are inevitable in spring jpa if you perform join.

Comment: Why are you using the JoinFetch annotation and setting it to be lazy loaded? Those two annotations would seem to conflict - it cannot be both fetched with the parent entity and only fetched if accessed - if you want it lazily fetched, remove the JoinFetch annotation on it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I removed JoinFetch, but lazy loading did not work.
As i understand, for ManyToOne i must enable dynamic weaving in EclipseLink:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving

However, i solved this problem via inheritance;

Answer (score 0):

For lazy loading in @ManyToOne i must enable dynamic weaving in EclipseLink:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving

I solved this problem via inheritance; 
I have created the base instance without relationship;

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class FacultyBase {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @Column(name = "university_id", nullable = false)
  private Long universityId;

}
```

and instance with relationship

```
@Entity
public class Faculty extends Faculty {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "university_id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private University university;

}
```

As a result, in Specialty instance i use FacultyBase instead of Faculty